# How to trim string (with Ideographic space U+3000) in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I have to trim Japanese characters string which has double byte space at start of string and end of string. 
I have to do this by procedure of SQL server 2016.

For Example,

```
SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(' A A '))
```

above one is working perfect

But Problem is in bellows line

```
SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM('　A　A　'))
```

i want output of above one is 'A　A'

Have any idea,  how to do this ?

Comment: No repro. `SELECT  '|'+LTRIM(RTRIM('  A　A  ')) + '|'` returns `|A A|`.

Comment: Getting same result from both your script. Not sure where is the issue :(

Comment: What does `double byte space` mean in the first place? Two spaces? Or some other whitespace character? BTW the SQL Server versions in the tags are unsupported, for quite some time now. It could be that *supported* versions succesfully handle the non-space character

Comment: @mkRabbani I copied the second script and added the REPLACE which gave back a result of 'A A'

Please check my edited post?

Comment: OK, I can verify that the problem occurs only on old SQL Server versions due to the  *non*space character used there. In SQL Server 2017 even that character is treated as space and trimmed. In fact, older versions will *mangle* that character because it's outside the normal character range. You should use `N'　A　A　'` instead

Comment: I have a idea but for that must have to create function and implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got solution
Thank you so much for your efforts. 
Please use this function for double byte space remove.**

CREATE FUNCTION [RTRIMBYTE](@AV_VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @AV_RETURN NVARCHAR(MAX) = @AV_VALUE;

WHILE DATALENGTH(@AV_RETURN) > 0 AND  RIGHT(@AV_RETURN, 1) in (' ', '　')
    SET @AV_RETURN = LEFT(@AV_RETURN, LEN('X' + @AV_RETURN + 'X') -3 ) ;

RETURN @AV_RETURN;
```

END;

Answer (score 2):

Adapted SQL from OP's post:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE('　A　A　', '  ', ' ')))
```

Screenshot with result:

[image]

Comment: No need for this as the OP's claim can't be reproduced

Comment: This won't work with the OP's string. It doesn't contain two spaces, it contains a single double-width whitespace character. Even if the search string is replaced with the double-width space, this will end up removing the space between the letters too

Comment: your Answer is 'AA' but i want 'A　A'. Means double byte space in both A

Comment: @NikunjChavda it's not a double-byte space. Saying this only confuses people. Use the correct name, or Unicode code instead

Comment: Strange... I'm getting the correct output with the proposed script. I used SSMS v18.14 with MSSQL v13.0.5492.2

Answer (score 1):

The space in that string is the [Ideographic space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) (U+3000) Unicode character, which LTRIM and RTRIM don't recognize as whitespace. Even TRIM in SQL Server 2017 won't recognize it unless it's specified explicitly.

Another problem is that this character is outside the normal range of characters and can't appear in a `varchar` field or value. This leads to inconsistent results between SQL Server versions. In SQL Server 2014 it will even appear as a `?`. In later versions LTRIM/RTRIM may or may not work without emitting the error character. I don't have access to all versions to test this.

In SQL Server 2017 it's possible to explicitly specify the trimmed character, eg :

```
select trim(N'　' from N'　A　A　')
```

This produces `A　A`.

In previous versions, `PATINDEX` can be used to find the locations of the first and last non-space positions :

```
declare @str nvarchar(10)=N'　A　A　';
declare @start int=PATINDEX(N'%[^　]%',@str)
declare @end int=PATINDEX(N'%　',@str)
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@str,@start,@end-@start)
```

The pattern `N'%[^　]%'` finds the first non-U+3000 character in the string. N'%　' finds the position of the last one. `SUBSTRING(@str,@start,@end-@start)` extracts the content between the two positions.

The result is:

`A　A`

Comment: Its working but,  what if you have to do this with all value of field.? i mean its not optimize way.

Comment: What do you mean? This *does* work on the entire field value and trims the unwanted character.